# Remotely accessing a router

Tags: networking, router, remote-access

I have two routers set up in my home, and I'm trying to make sure that my secondary router can be accessed "remotely" from my primary router (basically I want access to its settings page), but not from a computer/device on the internet. Unfortunately my secondary router is pretty crappy and when I enable Remote Management I can only select which port to connect to but I can't restrict access based on IP in any way.

My question is this: If remote access is disabled for may main router and my secondary router is connected to the main one via WAN does that mean that the secondary router can only be accessed "remotely" from within my local network (i.e. my main router), or am I making a terrible confusion here?

Comment: You don't need to enable "remote access" to access both routers from within your own network.  The remote access feature is designed to allow you to access the router from outside of your network (which is extremely insecure and shouldn't be done).

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the comment. I had already thought of doing it the way you said but I've tried it and it just doesn't work for some reason. If I try to access my secondary router using its local IP address it just won't respond. By the way, when I "remote" access it I actually just use a local address (192.168.0.152) followed by the port. Also in the router's settings page it only shows this IP as its WAN address, unlike my main router which has an external-looking WAN address.

Comment: @Ramhound Nevermind, I managed to figure it out. I had plugged the cable in the WAN port of the secondary router instead of a LAN port, I'm an idiot. Thanks for the help.